# Create new column for each unique value in other column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In my dataset I have value for each region(West, South, East and Central) at the start of each month from 2015-2018.

I need to transform the dataset in the next way: I want to create columns for each region remove column "Value":
Datetime Central West East South
2015-01-01 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4

How can I do it?[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GOKC.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `df.pivot`

```py
df.pivot(index='Datetime', columns='Region', values='Value').reset_index()
```